# A surprising result with the Riccati difference equation

Tags: cv.complex-variables, plane-geometry, recurrences

I was looking at the Riccati difference equation with positive and negative indices

$$
R_n=\frac{aR_{n-1}+b}{cR_{n-1}+d}\quad n\in[0,N]\\
R_n=\frac{-dR_{n+1}+b}{cR_{n+1}-a}\quad n\in[-N,0]\\
$$

along with its analytic continuation, call it $R_x, x\in[-N,N]$.

I have found that with real parameters $[a,b,c,d]$ and complex initial condition $R_0$, all the terms of the recurrence $R_n$ lie on a circle. The analytic continuation, however, may lie on that circle or be a compound spiral. The figures below show examples of both cases for randomly selected values of $[a,b,c,d,R_0]$. The blue and green dots show the positive and negative indices, respectively. The red asterisk is $R_0$ The analytic continuation is a black line. The cyan triangle, connecting any three dots of the recurrence, is the 'source' of the circumcircle that is seen to include all the recurrence terms.

Is there a known reason why this should not be a surprise? Something to do with the Möbius transformation perhaps?

[image: Circle on Analytic]

[image: Circle and Spirla]

Comment: You basically answered it yourself in the last sentence. You are acting with a linear fractional transformation corresponding to an $A\in SL(2,\mathbb R)$, and these are the automorphisms of the upper half plane. They preserve hyperbolic distance, so if $A$ has a fixed point $z_0\in\mathbb C^+$, then $d(Az,z_0)=d(z,z_0)$, so you stay on the (hyperbolic) circle about $z_0$, and this is also a Euclidean circle.

Comment: In general, it is of course not true, for example when $R_n=R_{n-1}+1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you.